# I need to open an Outlook email window from the button click on any browser with attachment

Tags: javascript, outlook, activex, mailto

I currently use ActiveX for that, but that, of course, only works in IE. JFYI I have used mailTo as well but using mailTo we cannot send attachment. Please let me know if there is any solution to this.

Comment: I do not think there is any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Create an EML file and provide a link to open it - Outlook will be happy to open it for you with attachments and everything else you include in the EML file.

Comment: But we have to enable this feature on client side and its a public facing environment.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "we have to enable this feature on client side".

Comment: It means that it's a public facing environment and we have to open Outlook email on every system accessing this feature along with the attachment.

Comment: That's fine - construct the MIME file using the local script in the browser and returns it to the user.

Comment: I have been able to create eml file but the browser ask it to download and then when i open it with outlook it successfully opens it. Is there any way this two step process of downloading eml and then manually opening with outlook is reduced to a single step where on button click the file automatically gets open in outlook?  Also using it the signature is not getting preserved. Please see the below code I am using:

Comment: <script>
function myFunction(){
var emlContent = "data:message/rfc822 eml;charset=utf-8,";
emlContent += 'To: yuvi@sds.com \n';
emlContent += 'Subject: dsdsds \n';
emlContent += 'X-Unsent: 1'+'\n';
emlContent += 'Content-Type: text/html'+'\n';
emlContent += '\n';
emlContent += '<a href="www.abc.com">htmlDocument<a>';

Comment: var encodedUri = encodeURI(emlContent); //encode spaces etc like a url
var a = document.createElement('a'); //make a link in document
var linkText = document.createTextNode("fileLink");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.href = encodedUri;
a.id = 'fileLink';
a.download = 'filename.eml';
a.style = "display:none;"; //hidden link
document.body.appendChild(a);
document.getElementById('fileLink').click(); //click the link
}

</script>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The prompt depends on the browser - IE can be configured to open the fiel immediately.